# Quais são as diferenças entre Power Query, Power Pivot, Power BI?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

Quero fazer uma contribuição para a comunidade, apresentando essas ferramentas gratuitas para a análise de dados usando a Microsoft e, infelizmente, são pouco conhecidas e exploradas por muitos e podem ser muito úteis em nosso trabalho de automação e criação de relatórios amplamente utilizados hoje no **Business Intelligence** porque permite analisar grandes volumes de dados no nosso já conhecido Microsoft Excel e é mais intuitivo para aqueles que não estão familiarizados com a "macros" VBA.

Espero que ao longo do tempo os rótulos **powerquery**, **powerbi** e **powerpivot** sejam preenchidos com perguntas para o uso dos idiomas **M** e **DAX**.

Nota: Estou aprendendo a falar português, sinta-se livre para editar esta postagem se você precisar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Power Query** É um [complemento](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=39379) desenvolvido a partir da versão do Excel 2010 e agora por padrão na versão 2016 como **Get & Transform**. Faz parte da proposta da Microsoft para o desenvolvimento do ETL por meio de sua sigla em inglês (Extract, Transform, Load) (Extract, Transform, Upload), muito consistente com a situação da análise de grandes volumes de informações para qualquer setor econômico e social.

PQ Permite conectar o Excel com múltiplas fontes de informações e transformá-las intuitivamente no **Query Editor**. Há uma quantidade considerável de ferramentas para transformar nossos dados, estes são armazenados passo a passo, dando-nos controle total sobre o processo de transformação.

[image]

Adicional apresenta o [idioma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/mt779182.aspx) **M** ou **Power M** para o mais avançado é a capacidade de acessar linha por linha ou passo a passo para editar a consulta e ser capaz de incorporar o resto das funções que eles não estão no ambiente básico do **editor de consulta**.

**Power Pivot** É outro [complemento](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?) [como](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZCO3y27z8E) PQ desenvolvido desde a versão de 2010 nativamente incorporada a partir da versão de 2013. Aqui podemos conectar várias fontes de informação ou com dados já transformados no Power Query. Graças à sua tecnologia de memória integrada, você pode armazenar milhões de registros sem grandes problemas contrários à nossa folha de Excel limitada.

Ele apresenta as [funções](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/gg413422.aspx) **DAX** que são desenvolvidas para formular e extrair informações de cubos de dados e nos permite criar métricas complexas e indicadores KPI (Key Performance Indicators).

Ele nos permite criar nossos modelos de dados de uma maneira relacionativa como já conhecemos no Access e, em seguida, visualizá-los usando nossas tabelas e gráficos dinâmicos tradicionais ou dinamicamente com **Power View** e **Power Maps**.

**PowerBI** é um [software](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) gratuito para a criação de painéis ou relatórios dinâmicos, onde também podemos encontrar o editor de consulta **Power Query** e as fórmulas **DAX**, com estes dois poderosos As ferramentas do PowerBI nos permitem analisar grandes volumes de informações e a possibilidade de compartilhá-los em nossa organização, localmente ou online, dependendo do caso.

[image]

[Video tutorial](https://youtu.be/lZA_r5aVetU)