# Unir dados de diferentes abas em uma só no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Tenho 18 planilhas(abas) com dados de usuários e preciso copiar e colar os dados em outra planilha(aba) de no nome consolidado. Preciso copiar o cabeçalho apenas da primeira planilha e ao final remover as linhas vazias.

Está tudo numa pasta de trabalho só. O cenário mais próximo que cheguei foi este mas está muito lento:

```
Sub juntarfim()
    '
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("PLANILHA1").Select
    Range("A5:E500").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CONSOLIDADOJUNTOS").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '
    Range("A501").Select
    Sheets("PLANILHA2").Select
    Range("A6:E500").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CONSOLIDADOJUNTOS").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '
End sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se você tiver o Excel 2010+, poderá usar o Power Query em vez de macros do VBA. É mais fácil e eficiente. siga estas etapas:

[image]

Aqui eu faço uma pequena revisão:
[Quais são as diferenças entre Power Query, Power Pivot, Power BI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273342/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-power-query-power-pivot-power-bi)

No caso da macro, você pode revisar linha por linha com <kbd>F8</kbd>:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim i, WS_Count, WS_Count2 As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "All"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

WS_Count = Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets.Count 'contar quantas folhas estão no livro

For i = 1 To WS_Count - 1 'Nesta linha, faça uma iteração para cada página do livro, exceto ALL
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
    Range("A2:C" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All").Activate
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: muito obrigado!